# Android Studio Google Play Services no autocomplete

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

I use AS 0.4.2 then imported GMS as described in doc:
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.+'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30' }
```

all what is detected by IDE is R class, but rest of code is invisible.
On the other hand I put following code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
(...)
    private void connectGms(){
        Log.d(MbcConstants.TAG,
                "check for gms"+ GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                        isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this));
    }
```

And it works, but IDE still shows class name in red, but properly shows the params and returned type for method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - it seems like a bug in Android studio.
What I've done do fix it:
remove all dependencies (use F4 key) from project and the module
delete files from projectroot/.idea/libraries

open the module gradle.buld

add back all dependencies that are needed by your project to work. In my case:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

Synchronize gradle.build once again

Continue your adventure of love and hate or return to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

All you needed to do was hit the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button after editing the `build.gradle` file by hand.