# Android Studio and google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm getting really frustrated with this. I've managed to make the google play services available in Android Studio but now I can't instantiate an `AdView` class. I can import `import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;` no errors there, it just says `Unused import` but when I try to create an `AdView` class I get a `cannot find symbol` error. It also doesn't find `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` or any other class inside that package for that matter.

I tried cleaning/re-building/restarting the IDE but nothing worked so far.

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}

productFlavors {
    defaultFlavor {
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
 }
```

## Fixed

**See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068685/android-studio-google-play-services-no-autocomplete)**